# Adding an OpenLDAP server directory to a MacOS system via terminal

Tags: openldap, mac

Little background, I'm writing an installer that will do everything I need to do for me, right now I'm trying to figure out how to add an OpenLDAP directory to my macOS (client is the mac) via the terminal. In order to add LDAP servers you do the following:

- Go to settings and Users & Groups
- Login Options
- Click "Join" next to Network Account Server
- Add the server
- Check allow network users to login and click edit
- Go to open directory utility and click LDAPv3
- From mappings -> RFC2307
- Add the search base
- Fix the hash types depending on the macOS client version

(For visual representation see [here](https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/how-to-connect-mac-client-devices-to-the-ldap-directory-service-and-access-files-in-qnap-nas/)). What I need to do is to do all if this from the terminal. Is there a way for me to follow all these steps using a command?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the answer, but so far I'm using the following command to start with.

sudo dsconfigldap -a server.domain.com

This creates the LDAP server in Directory Utility.

I'm still working on the RFC2307 part.

dscl -q localhost -create /Search SearchPolicy dsAttrTypeStandard:CSPSearchPath
sudo dscl -q localhost -merge /Search CSPSearchPath /LDAPv3/server.domain.com